# [Django][MultipleChoiceField] Passing checkboxes values to server

Tags: python, django, forms, checkbox, multiplechoicefield

could you let me know how to pass my checkbox values to server?

views.py

```
def viewtest(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form=testForm(request.POST)
        if(form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    elif request.method == "GET":
        form=testForm()
    return render(request,"test/register.html",{"testform":form})
```

forms.py

```
class testForm(forms.ModelForm):
    workday=forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), choices=workdayType)
    class Meta:
        model=test
        fields=('name','tel')
```

register.html

```
 <table>
    <form method="post" action="{% url "viewtest" %}">
        {{testform.as_table}}
    </form>
    <input type="submit" value="register"/>
  </table>
```

I can see like below checkboxes.
[image]

but at server, can't see multiple data. could you provide me some idea?

Answer (score -1):

there was my silly stuff. because I've used getting POST data as request.POST['workday']. it was wrong. I SHOULD USE form.cleaned_data.get("workday"). that's for my solution. But don't know what is different yet.